# oops python if elfi error

Tags: python, oop

```
   def book_search(self,match):
        self.match = match
        for inum in range(len(self.mybooksinventory)):
            if (self.match == self.mybooksinventory[inum]['name']):
               print ("Congrats You Book is available")
               self.book_details_print(inum)
            elif (self.match == self.mybooksinventory[inum]['stuclass']):
               print ("Congrats You Book is available")
               self.book_details_print(inum)
            elif (self.match == self.mybooksinventory[inum]['subject']):
               print ("Congrats You Book is available")
               self.book_details_print(inum)
            else:
               print ("+" * 55)
               print ("Book You are looking for is not available")
```

```
[bookstore]# ./Book.py
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Book You are looking for is not available
Congrats You Book is available
*******************************************************
Name: India
for student of class: Arts
Subject: History
Language of Book is: English
[root@su01897 bookstore]#
```

Problem : when i am able to search book , which is correct ...then why my program is also saying that "Book You are looking for is not available" from else loop ...**if condition is true then why it is going in else loop.**

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your error.

Comment: You search the entire list of books. So the `else` will happen for every book in the list, except the match. You only want to print the error message _after_ you've searched the list and haven't found a match (outside the `for`).

Comment: If the condition is true it does not go to the else block - the programming language is not broken. If it goes to an else block then the conditional is false. Period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `break` after successfull response in if/elif.

```
 def book_search(self,match):
    self.match = match
    is_match = False
    for inum in range(len(self.mybooksinventory)):
        if (self.match == self.mybooksinventory[inum]['name']):
           print ("Congrats You Book is available")
           self.book_details_print(inum)
           is_match = True
           break
        elif (self.match == self.mybooksinventory[inum]['stuclass']):
           print ("Congrats You Book is available")
           self.book_details_print(inum)
           is_match = True
           break
        elif (self.match == self.mybooksinventory[inum]['subject']):
           print ("Congrats You Book is available")
           self.book_details_print(inum)
           is_match = True
           break
        else:
            is_match = False


    if is_match == False:
        print ("+" * 55)
        print ("Book You are looking for is not available")
```

Comment: It does not work for me ..code is not working                                                         [root@su01897 bookstore]# ./Book.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Book.py", line 18, in <module>
    class BooksInventory(object):
  File "./Book.py", line 79, in BooksInventory
    if is_match == False:
NameError: name 'is_match' is not defined
[root@su01897 bookstore]#

Comment: [root@su01897 bookstore]# ./Book.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Book.py", line 18, in <module>
    class BooksInventory(object):
  File "./Book.py", line 79, in BooksInventory
    if is_match == False:
NameError: name 'is_match' is not defined
[root@su01897 bookstore]#